# The contents of the variable outside the function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that writes to the variable files from the input file field. I want to re-load files in the variable after reselecting files in the form. The current script loads the files correctly, but the previous files are in the upload variable. How to clean up the variable upload before each call to the load_files function in such a way that the variable data is available outside of it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.choose-input').on('change', load_files);
  var upload = [];

  function load_files(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);  
    arr.forEach(function(file) {
      upload.push(file);
      $('.choose-el').append(file.name);
    });

    if (upload.length > 0) {
      $('.choose-el').append('<span class="start-upload">Start upload</span>');
    }

    $('.choose-input').val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Are you just asking how to clear the contents of an array?

Comment: How to clean up the variable upload before each call to the load_files function in such a way that the variable data is available outside of it

Comment: What do you mean by `in such a way that the variable data is available outside of it` ?

Comment: I want to use the upload variable with data beyond the load_files function. Example: in the function of uploading files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var upload = [];
$('.choose-input').on('change', function(e) {
  upload = [];
  load_files(e);
);
```

Comment: Works correctly, I did not bump into it !. Good job